# the reason behind dual the inner problem in robust optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have reading some material about Robust optimization.
It seems that dual optimization theory is the main techniques to reformulate robust optimization.

for example:
$$\min_x\qquad c^Tx$$
$$s.t\qquad a^Tx\leq b$$

where$$\qquad a\in \{a|Da\leq d\} $$

and the problem is equivalent 
$$\min_x\qquad c^Tx$$
$$s.t\qquad \max_{Da\leq d}a^Tx\leq b$$

and they use dual theory reformulate the max problem to min problem

which is 
 $$\min_x\qquad c^Tx$$
$$s.t\qquad \min_{D^Tp=x,p\geq0}p^Td\leq b$$

and  finally it equivalent to   $$\min_{x,p}\qquad c^Tx$$
$s.t$ 
$$p^Td\leq b$$
$$D^Tp=x$$
$$p\geq0$$

My question is

1.why we use dual theory to reformulate the inner problem?

2.why we can omit the second minimize in constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We use duality theory because we can do 'step 2'. It is a technique to turn a problem with uncountable many constraints into something manageable.
2. If you can find one $p \geq 0$ for which $D^Tp = x$ and $p^T d \leq b$, that is already sufficient to conclude that the minimum over $p\geq 0$  for which $D^Tp=x$ is less than or equal to $b$.

Comment: thanks for your reply,but I still have confusion here.
1.as you mentioned,I know the problem have infinite constraints,but I don't know what happen to  those infinite constraints, when we dualize the inner problem,can you give me some detail illustrated?

Comment: and for the question 2,why is already sufficient to conclude.....
is that any theorem or prove to illustrate this thing? i.e KKT condition or something ele?
thank you!

Comment: @VergilChan the infinite constraints went into a modest number of constraints. It is clear that the final formulation is just a regular linear optimization problem. It is sufficient to conclude from the definition of the minimum: the minimum of a set is not larger than any element of a set.

Answer (score 0):

There are two points that need to be noted:

1. The variables in the objective function and the subproblem are different. Hence the minimization problem in the constraints does not influence the feasible region of $x$ directly.
2. Since the subproblem in the constraints is an optimization problem in the format:
   $min \ f(x)\leq b$ (it also works for $max \ f(x)\geq b$), the constraint can be meet as long as we can find a feasible solution meets $f(x)\leq b$ (or $f(x)\geq b$). Hence, we can just convert the optimization problem into inequality constraints.